# Get FileInfo of a file on server

Tags: vb.net, http, uri, fileinfo

I have a file with the following uri `http://10.20.80.001/mobilepayment/hi.cer` published in iis . Is there any way to get the date created of this file in vb??
I want something like this

```
Dim fullpath = http://10.20.80.001/mobilepayment/hi.cer
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(fullpath)
Dim Filetimestamp As String = infoReader.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyMMddHHmmss")
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually GET the file from the URI.  Until you've done that it is just a string.

So either perform a web request and download it to a temporary location, then use that location as your "fullpath" OR when you request it inspect the HTTP headers for the last modified date.

Comment: But I won't get the right creation date of the original file. I'll get the date when I downloaded the file. I want to get the original one, The date of Creation of "http://10.20.80.001/mobilepayment/hi.cer"

Comment: please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352736/get-creation-date-of-a-file-on-the-web