# Get Creation Date of a file on the web

Tags: vb.net, file, http, creation, last-modified

I know this question was already asked here: [Get File Creation Date Over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326604/get-file-creation-date-over-http)

BUT, I didn't get the answer needed. I don't want to get the "Last Modified" date. Instead I want the creation date.

The following code gets me the last modified date from the headers.

```
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://10.20.80.111/mobilepayment/myfile.crt"), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)

        Dim lastmodified As String

        Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

            lastmodified = response.Headers("last-modified").ToString()
        End Using
```

Is there a way I can get the creation date? please help!

Answer (score 1):

No, in plain HTTP there is no standard header field for that.

(WebDAV does have a property for it, though: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4918.html#PROPERTY_creationdate)

Comment: I've been searching all morning for this. I still have no idea how to implement it. Could you help me?